# unhandled exception from dll - only shows up in release build

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a dll library that I built to help reduce the amount of boilerplate code copied over from project to project. There is a timer running in the dll to maintain the connection to our machinery via RPC. When I debug my project and break the RPC connection my code gracefully tosses a disconnect event from the dll library and my main form catches the event and handles it appropriately.

Now, build for release. When I break the RPC connection a unhandled exception is tossed from the library that apparently is not caught elsewhere.

The weird part is that the code that is throwing the exception is in the timer and the calls are all wrapped in try/catch blocks and the catch block swallows the exception and does other cleanup work.

I don't get how in debug mode everything is fine but in release it is not. That part doesn't make sense to me. I tried looking at the exception object and setting a handled property on it but it's not available. Is this normal behavior what I am seeing?

I just recently started utilizing numerous libraries in my projects to keep my solutions more trimmed and easy to follow. Hopefully this isn't a problem with libraries I had not considered.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem. Try adding some log functions, in order to find out from where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some types of exceptions which aren't caught in a Try-Catch in Release mode, for example those happening in a different thread. Try handling the [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) event in your main form.

You can also handle [Application.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to make sure all unhandled exceptions are caught.

Comment: Make sure you also attach to the Application.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event like the example at the link above shows.

Comment: I do not normally attach to these events. I'll give it a shot. If this is a thread related exception then does the debugger control the thread context and that's why I don't see it when i step through the code?

Comment: well I added a handler for threadexception but my issue was still not caught by it and the unhandled exception handler gracefully shut down my application. To fix the problem, I had to move my classes out of my dll and back into my main project. Then I was able to catch the error every time it occurred.